# What is the difference between XSD choice and enumeration?

Tags: xml, xsd

What is the difference between XSD choice and enumeration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are completely unrelated.

Choice indicates that within the content model of an element, you can use one of several child elements: for example within a document you have a choice of chapter or appendix as child elements.

Enumeration is used to restrict the values that can appear in a text or attribute node, for example to say that the value of a color attribute must be red, green, or blue.

Answer (score 3):

XSD choice allows you to choose between zero or one elements/attributes. These can be of any type.

Enumeration are used in XSD simpleTypes to either restrict or extend one particular type to a set of values.

Comment: +1 for the distinction between **elements** and **values**. How one phrases it (choice vs. restriction) is confusing. The bottom line is that [both](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395647/1864054) select/chose/pick. That said, `choice` has a feature that `enumeration` doesn't: The ability to have `maxOccurs="unbounded"`

Answer (score 1):

Gathering from the previous answers, and putting them together in clear, concise way:

The differences are two-fold:

- `choice` is for element tag, and `enumeration` is for a node's text or attribute.
- `choice` allows for zero instances, while `enumeration` requires one.