# why some schemas use <xsd:choice> instead of <xsd:enumeration>?

Tags: xsd

I saw an xml schema ( [EPP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5730) ) whitch used `xsd:choice` with an element even if we can use `xsd:enumeration` instead :

```
 <element name="access" type="epp:dcpAccessType"/>
    <complexType name="dcpAccessType">
      <choice>
        <element name="all"/>
        <element name="none"/>
        <element name="null"/>
        <element name="other"/>
        <element name="personal"/>
        <element name="personalAndOther"/>
      </choice>
    </complexType>
```

**to make the question clear , I will use this example instead :**

```
<element name="sport" type="sportType"/>

<!-- using choice-->
<complexType name="sportType">
  <choice>
    <element name="football"/>
    <element name="tennis"/>
  </choice>
</complexType>

<!-- Or using enumeration-->
<simpleType name="sportType">
  <restriction base="string">
    <enumeration value="football"/>
    <enumeration value="tennis"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

**an xml example using that schema  :**

```
<!--using choice-->
<sport>
  <football/>
</sport>

<!--using enumeration-->
<sport>football</sport>
```

why they prefer `xsd:choice` instead of `xsd:enumeration` **in this situation** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why they prefer xsd:choice instead of xsd:enumeration in this situation ?

Presumably they want a tag instead of text content in the supported xml.

The decision to use one or the other is pretty much a matter of xml you want to support, as they do quite different things.  Which xml form is preferable is quite subjective.

See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358132/what-is-the-difference-between-xsd-choice-and-enumeration).

Answer (score 3):

Choice is for choice between elements, while enumeration allow choice between a set of values. The values can be string like in your example, but if you wanted to enumerate several element objects, then you would have to use choice.